# Import products to WooCommerce by CSV page won't open

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, import

I've been asked to update a high street shop and make a section for online shopping. I'm no Wordpress whizz, but experiencing a steep learning curve.
I'm using WooCommerce and it's working great so far except that the function to import products from a CSV file (not a plugin, just their own function) is no longer working! Whenever I click at the top of the products page to import, the browser takes a while and then comes up with an error of too many redirects.

I've tried looking on other forums for redirecting errors in Wordpress, I've tried editing the shop URL and Wordpress URL to include/exclude "www." and this doesn't work. The only result I get if I add "www." to either is that when I click on "import", the dashboard loads.

I have no idea what is causing this!! Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, having the exact same issue. Can't find a solution.